# The name convention for returned files in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a controller located in `/admin/users/users_controller.rb`:

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #..........
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # the file /admin/users/index.html.haml will be returned implicitly 
      format.js   # the file /admin/users/index.js.erb will be returned implicitly 
    end 
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
 namespace :admin do
  resource :users do
    collection do
     resources :tags, controller: :users_tags
    end
  end
 end
```

If I have a controller `UsersTagsController` in the same directory:

```
class Admin::UsersTagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     #..........
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # what file will be returned?
       format.js   # what file will be returned?
     end 
  end
end
```

So what file will be returned in this case?

Comment: Why don’t you run it and access the action in question and see what file it complains about being missing?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall due to laziness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files / views returned would be based on the location of the controller and not the format of the route. E.g they would be  located at `admin/users_tags/index.{format}.erb` (assuming the `UsersTagsController` is located at `controllers/admin/users_tags_controller.rb`)

On a side note, normally the namespaced `Admin::UsersController` would be located at `controllers/admin/users_controller.rb` and not `controllers/admin/users/users_controller.rb`